# sencha touch :: how to avoid slowing down iOS apps (inside phonegap)

Tags: iphone, performance, cordova, sencha-touch

is there anywhere a list of "avoid-this" when building a iOS/phonegap app with sencha touch?

maybe it is slowing down the app on iphone when

```
setActiveItem(Ext.create(newCard), 'slide');
```

is used (?)

and things like that.

thanx!

Comment: actually this is speeding up when used with `container.on('deactivate', function(oldCard){
 oldCard.destroy();
});`
:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) A link to some general web-app performance best practices: [Here](http://mir.aculo.us/2010/06/04/making-an-ipad-html5-app-making-it-really-fast/)

2) A Sencha dev's comments on the article: [Here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?101813-Great-article-for-tips-on-optimizing-performance-on-the-iPhone-and-iPad)

3) More Sencha Touch performance considerations: [Here](http://www.slideshare.net/senchainc/optimizing-performance)

4) Another helpful discussion on the topic: [Here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?57839-List-of-performance-strategies-for-extjs)